# How to identify conda package dependents?

Tags: conda

**For a given `conda` package, how to I list the packages that depend on it?**

I recently installed anaconda on a university cluster that already had a version of MPI (openmpi). The `mpich2` package and `mpi4py` packages installed with anaconda were fine for demos of mpi4py, but the `mpi*` compilers (mpicc, etc) were not compatable. So I `conda remove`'d `mpich2` and `mpi4py` and used `pip` to install `mpi4py` using the local MPI install and compilers.

I had to dig around to find `mpi4py`'s dependencies and then `mpich2`'s dependents, for which I only identified `mpi4py`. **Is there an "easy" way to find out what depends on `mpich2`?**

Comment: Is parsing your story about MPI necessary to understand your question, or does your opening sentence cover it?

Comment: @duozmo I'd guess the opening statement covers it, but I usually like to give context to my questions in case I'm not asking the right question.

Comment: No objection to providing context. It's just a fairly involved scenario and I was spending a lot of time trying to figure out if we had the same question (your opening sentence).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Searching the package cache will only show you the packages that you have downloaded already. For your case, this behavior is fine, but if you want to know every package that depends on a given package, a better way is to search the repodata of your channels. The repodata is cached in `~/anaconda/pkgs/cache`, or you can navigate with your browser to http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/ and click on `repodata.json` for the platform you use (for Binstar, go to, e.g., https://conda.binstar.org/asmeurer). Then search for the name of the package in the "depends" key.

Comment: Would be nice to have this information easily accessible online.

Comment: And now it is! :)

Comment: Great answer, most repos I've seen have also `repodata.json.bz2` which downloads faster. The cache has almost the same data, except for a few keys in the JSON, like `_url`, `_mod`, `_cache_control` - If it wasn't for this information, I wouldn't know which channel this is for (the cache JSON filenames are some obscure hashes).

Answer (score 45):

`conda info` will tell you the directory (or directories) where your `package cache` is located. These directories contain a unique directory for each package, and each package directory contains an `info` directory and a file called `index.json`. There is a `requires` field in each of these files that refers to a list of `conda` dependencies. So in short, you need to search these files for the package you're trying to remove.

For example, if `anaconda`'s installed in my home directory, and therefore the package cache is `~/anaconda/pkgs`, to find `mpich2`'s dependents, I would:

```
grep mpich2 ~/anaconda/pkgs/*/info/index.json
```

You will see 2 lines for the `anaconda` package, because `mpich2` is both in the aforementioned `requires` list and in a list called `depends`. You'll also see one line for each `mpich2` package available, because there is also a `name` field for each package. Then you'll see one or more lines for each package that depends on, requires  `mpich2`. My search produced only `mpi4py`.

Now I thought you could do a `--dry-run` remove, but it appears that `remove` does not remove dependents, so nothing special is listed.

If `grep` is unavailable, then I'm sure you could make a python script to do the same thing, using say the `glob`module and maybe even `json` to do the searching.

Comment: Useful tip about `conda info`! Also note - if you want to script something using this information, check out `conda info --json`.

Answer (score 25):

With recent versions of conda, you can do

```
conda remove --dry-run <package>
```

to get a list of packages that would be uninstalled along with the given one.

Answer (score 23):

This has been solved in 2023, please read the [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77790581/9201239).

---

The old answer:

```
conda search --reverse-dependency <package>
```

should be the answer. Except it's not working. Please vote on this [issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6670) to show that it's important to users. It's been reported in Jan-18 and there has been no change in status. Hopefully if enough votes is gathered it'll be looked at. Or perhaps someone could submit a PR to fix it.

Until then you may have a partial solution using [pipdeptree](https://github.com/naiquevin/pipdeptree) if pip's version of the package's reverse dependencies are identical to conda's version, which is often not the case. But at least it will give you some indication.

```
pipdeptree --reverse --packages <package>
```

Answer (score 11):

### `mamba repoquery`

While [Mamba](https://mamba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) is primarily a drop-in replacement for Conda, one of the extra features it provides is solid functionality for dependency and reverse dependency querying through its [`repoquery` command](https://mamba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/mamba.html#repoquery). However, note that this is only for environment-level relationships, so the packages must be installed and the environment activated.

### Demo

Note that this is years out from the original question, so I'm just going demo with a `mpi4py` install and use the versions that get installed.

```bash
$ mamba create -n so-mpi4py mpi4py
## installs 24 packages

$ conda activate so-mpi4py
(so-mpi4py) $ mamba repoquery whoneeds mpich
                  __    __    __    __
                 /  \  /  \  /  \  /  \
                /    \/    \/    \/    \
███████████████/  /██/  /██/  /██/  /████████████████████████
              /  / \   / \   / \   / \  \____
             /  /   \_/   \_/   \_/   \    o \__,
            / _/                       \_____/  `
            |/
        ███╗   ███╗ █████╗ ███╗   ███╗██████╗  █████╗
        ████╗ ████║██╔══██╗████╗ ████║██╔══██╗██╔══██╗
        ██╔████╔██║███████║██╔████╔██║██████╔╝███████║
        ██║╚██╔╝██║██╔══██║██║╚██╔╝██║██╔══██╗██╔══██║
        ██║ ╚═╝ ██║██║  ██║██║ ╚═╝ ██║██████╔╝██║  ██║
        ╚═╝     ╚═╝╚═╝  ╚═╝╚═╝     ╚═╝╚═════╝ ╚═╝  ╚═╝

        mamba (0.19.0) supported by @QuantStack

        GitHub:  https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba
        Twitter: https://twitter.com/QuantStack

█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████


Executing the query mpich



 Name   Version Build           Depends              Channel           
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 mpi4py 3.1.3   py310hd348148_0 mpich >=3.4,<4.0.0a0 conda-forge/osx-64
```

Personally, I usually use the tree format, with

```bash
(so-mpi4py) $ mamba repoquery whoneeds --tree mpich

mpich[3.4.2]
  └─ mpi4py[3.1.3]
```

### Real-World Example

More of a testimonial to its usefulness, I had noticed at some point that one of my R environments somehow ended up with Python installed. I'm very strict about this, so I reached for `mamba repoquery whoneeds` and found:

```bash
(bioc_3_12) host:dir usr$ mamba repoquery whoneeds -t python

Executing the query python

python[3.9.2]
  ├─ numpy[1.20.2]
  │  └─ colormath[3.0.0]
  │     └─ spectra[0.0.11]
  │        └─ r-rspectra[0.16_0]     # <- this package is the culprit!
  │           └─ r-uwot[0.1.10]
  ├─ networkx[2.5]
  │  └─ colormath already visited
  ├─ certifi[2021.5.30]
  │  └─ setuptools[49.6.0]
  │     ├─ networkx already visited
  │     └─ pip[21.0.1]
  ├─ python_abi[3.9]
  │  ├─ numpy already visited
  │  ├─ certifi already visited
  │  └─ setuptools already visited
  ├─ colormath already visited
  ├─ spectra already visited
  ├─ decorator[4.4.2]
  │  └─ networkx already visited
  ├─ wheel[0.36.2]
  │  └─ pip already visited
  ├─ pip already visited
  └─ setuptools already visited
```

Turned out the `r-spectra` package recipe in Conda Forge had [misstated one of its dependencies](https://github.com/conda-forge/r-rspectra-feedstock/issues/12) to be a Python package (`spectra`) rather than a C++ dynamic library (`spectralib`).

Answer (score 7):

There is a conda package for this: [conda-tree](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/conda-tree). [Documentation](https://github.com/rvalieris/conda-tree).

To find packages that depend on a package:

```
# which packages depend on a specific package
$ conda-tree whoneeds xz
['samtools', 'bcftools', 'htslib', 'python']
```

You could also dump the entire dependency tree, and then search:

```
# full dependency tree
$ conda-tree deptree --full
neovim==0.3.1
  ├─ pynvim 0.3.2 [required: any]
  │  ├─ greenlet 0.4.15 [required: any]
...
```

Answer (score 5):

Sometime in 2023 conda finally added a working solution:

`conda repoquery whoneeds`

Example:

```
$ conda repoquery whoneeds -c conda-forge accelerate
Collecting package metadata: done
 Name                 Version     Build             Depends                Channel     Subdir  
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 autogluon.multimodal 0.6.2       py38h578d9bd_2    accelerate <0.14,>=0.9 conda-forge linux-64
 autogluon.multimodal 0.6.2       py38h578d9bd_3    conda-forge            linux-64   
 autogluon.multimodal 0.6.2       py38h578d9bd_4    conda-forge            linux-64   
[...]
 autogluon.multimodal 0.8.0       py39h4655687_1    conda-forge            linux-64
 autogluon.multimodal 0.8.0       py39h764a5bb_0    conda-forge            linux-64
 gradsflow            0.0.7.post2 pyhd8ed1ab_0      conda-forge            noarch
 gradsflow            0.0.8       pyhd8ed1ab_0      conda-forge            noarch
[...]
```

Answer (score 4):

Shameless plug: [conda-depgraph](https://github.com/omegacen/conda-depgraph) can do this fairly easily:

```
$ conda depgraph --from-channels in mpich2

 ┌────────┐
 │anaconda│
 └───┬─┬──┘
     │ │
     │ └──┐
     v    │
 ┌──────┐ │
 │mpi4py│ │
 └──┬───┘ │
    │ ┌───┘
    │ │
    v v
 ┌──────┐
 │mpich2│
 └──────┘
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on Yann's answer, code diving in conda core and reading [this](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#listing-package-dependencies) I came up with the following script to get a reverse-dependency graph of all cached channels:

```
import glob
import json
import os

from collections import defaultdict

info = json.load(os.popen('conda info --json'))

print('Loading channels...')
channels = [
    json.load(open(repodata))
    for pkg_dir in info['pkgs_dirs']
    for repodata in glob.glob(os.path.join(pkg_dir, 'cache', '*.json'))
]
print('Done')

rdeps = defaultdict(set)

for c in channels:
    for k, v in c['packages'].items():
        package = '-'.join(k.split('-')[:-2])
        for dep in v['depends']:
            dependant = dep.split()[0]
            rdeps[dependant].add((package, c['_url']))
```

Now you can get the reverse dependencies of a specific package:

```
>>> print(rdeps['mpich2'])
set()
```

Well, right now nothing depends on it anymore... But if you run it in ipython or Jupyter, you can then quickly query the reverse dependencies, e.g.:

```
>>> print(rdeps['aiosqlite'])
{('databases', 'https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64')}
```

You get the package name (without versions, of which there may be many), and the channel URL (which can show you, if it's `pkgs/main/(arch)` or `conda-forge` etc.

Comment: `$ conda_rd () { python -c 'from reverse_dependency import rdeps; print(rdeps['$1'])' ; }`

Comment: That's a nice bash function! We just need to make this module importable from everywhere.