# How do I specify project dependencies separate from Conda environments?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Rubygems uses two files, `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`.  The former specifies the dependencies of the current project; the latter specifies which packages were actually installed in order to satisfy those dependencies.  This way, you get reproducible environments (in `Gemfile.lock`) while being able to change project dependencies (in `Gemfile`) without worrying.

As far as I can tell, Conda's `environment.yml` is similar in function to `Gemfile.lock`.  You can install a bunch of packages manually and reproduce that environment on another machine with `environment.yml`.  But it's hard to remove a library, because I can't tell whether a library listed in `environment.yml` was added by explicit installation or whether it was added as a dependency for a different package that I installed.

So I'd like to have an automatically managed file which merely lists my project's dependencies, and have Conda generate an environment which satisfies those dependencies.  Is this possible with Conda?

(Alternatively, is there some other way that heavy users of Anaconda get around this problem?)

Comment: So if you have an empty environment and do `conda install numpy` you would like to have just `numpy` specified when you do `conda env export` and not everything that comes with numpy e.g. mkl, wheel..... ?

Comment: @Hami yes, that's what I'd like.  Or any other solution which also allows me to remove packages that I explicitly installed without removing packages that were installed as library dependencies.

Comment: Somewhat related https://stackoverflow.com/a/26101973/633093
Honestly I don`t think there is an easy way to do this.