# Create new conda environment with latest python AND all the packages that I've added in an existing environment

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I want to create new conda environment with latest python (want 3.10 or later) AND the appropriate versions of all the packages (like matplotlib and pandas) that I've added in an existing environment (it's NOT the base environment). I don't recall what all of these packages are. Is there a way to do this without breaking things?

Comment: Maybe export the environment to a yaml file, then modify the python version in that file, and create a new env from that file?

Comment: I know that I can do that, but what I don't know is if this risks getting versions of packages that are incompatible with the newer version of python. Do you know if this will be a problem or not?

Comment: I think the only way to find out is to try to build the environment with the newer python version. The installation will fail if there is an incompatibility.

Comment: If you're going to change Python version, you'll need at least the `--no-builds` flag when dumping to YAML, since all compiled Python packages are version-specific. Otherwise, yeah, I agree with @.jkr: dump YAML, edit, recreate, if failing then edit to loosen package versions, and iterate until working.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all package versions with [`pip freeze`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_freeze/).
Put these in a `requirements.txt` file.
Create a new environment with the appropriate python version.
Now install all packages with `pip install -r requirements.txt`

The [Conda way](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#create-env-file-manually) to export all packages is `conda env export > environment.yml`.

In the environment file, modify the python version if needed, and remove unnecessary packages.
Create the new environment using `conda env create -f environment.yml`. If there is a conflict (e.g. dependency) [it will tell you](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/troubleshooting.html?highlight=conflict).

Also, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26101972/how-to-identify-conda-package-dependents) question for dealing with cross-dependencies.

Comment: Will this include the appropriate versions of the packages for the newer version of python? 
Also, I'd prefer an approach that used conda installs rather than pip.

Comment: @ViennaMike, see the modified response per your comment.